# Using chrome frame instead of SockJS

Tags: websocket, push-notification, go, google-chrome-frame, sockjs

I'm creating web application using Go programming language.

In my project I need to support IE>=8, Firefox >=13 Opera >=12 ... 
A part of the project rely on realtime push notification. Go doesn't have good support for Socket.IO or SockJS to abstract from http push methods, but it has buildin support for websockets.

I want to  implement the realtime push module in Go using Go websockets - inside the http web application instead of creating other service in other language which uses SockJS. This will require IE8, IE9 users to install [chrome frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) plugin.

**Q:** Are there any drawbacks of this solution, besides forcing IE8 and IE9 users to install chrome frame?

**Q2** Are there any pros for having separate service for push notification? (besides having better browser compatibility)?

The pros is that I don't need to maintain separate service and I can reuse Go code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a good idea of the trade-off. Only you can know if installing chrome frame will be acceptable to your users.

If you only/mostly need to push data TO the users then also look at the EventSource API. It is more widely supported and very simple to implement on the server.

Comment: Thank you. On the opposite: Are there any pros for having separate service for push notification? (besides having better browser compatibility)? support for EventSource is similar (IE10 doesn't support it but it has slightly better compatibility with other browsers).

Comment: And there is no chrome frame for IE10.

Comment: My stupid: EventSource is regular HTTP, so we can add 3rd party JS lib to support it for browsers without native EventSource.

Comment: Yeah, exactly - for browsers without native support the workarounds aren't so awful/complex.